# AdMobInterstitial [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Ad is already loaded.]

Tags: react-native, expo, admob, hadoop-yarn, interstitial

I have been applying ads and the app shows only ad once,
if the the ad is closed
and making the add to show

The add shows only once
and to make it show again
i have to reload he app or restart the app

it shows this..

[Click here for Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cb5oC.png)

And these are my dependencies
"dependencies": {
"@react-native-admob/admob": "^2.0.1",
"@react-native-firebase/admob": "^11.5.0",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
"autofix": "^0.5.8",
"expo": "~45.0.0",
"expo-ads-admob": "~13.0.0",
"expo-ads-facebook": "~11.2.0",
"expo-cli": "^5.4.9",
"expo-facebook": "~12.2.0",
"expo-splash-screen": "~0.15.1",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
"expo-system-ui": "~1.2.0",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-dom": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.68.2",
"react-native-ad-manager": "^1.3.9",
"react-native-admob": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
"react-native-admob-ads": "^1.0.3",
"react-native-ads-facebook": "^0.2.0",
"react-native-event-listeners": "^1.0.7",
"react-native-fbads": "^7.1.0",
"react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^6.3.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "4.2.4",
"react-native-screens": "~3.11.1",
"react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
"react-native-web": "0.17.7",
"yarn": "^1.22.19"
},

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your interstitial ad listener it will reload your interstitial ad after it's closed

```
 if (type === AdEventType.CLOSED) {
      console.log("ad closed")
      setLoaded(false)
      //reload ad
      interstitial.load()
 }
```

Example:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { Button } from "react-native"
import {
  InterstitialAd,
  AdEventType,
  TestIds
} from "@react-native-firebase/admob"

const adUnitId = __DEV__
  ? TestIds.INTERSTITIAL
  : "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyyyyyyyy"

const interstitial = InterstitialAd.createForAdRequest(adUnitId, {
  requestNonPersonalizedAdsOnly: true,
  keywords: ["fashion", "clothing"]
})

function App() {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    const eventListener = interstitial.onAdEvent((type) => {
      if (type === AdEventType.LOADED) {
        setLoaded(true)
      }
      if (type === AdEventType.CLOSED) {
        console.log("ad closed")
        setLoaded(false)
        //reload ad
        interstitial.load()
      }
    })

    // Start loading the interstitial straight away
    interstitial.load()

    // Unsubscribe from events on unmount
    return () => {
      eventListener()
    }
  }, [])

  // No advert ready to show yet
  if (!loaded) {
    return null
  }

  return (
    <Button
      title="Show Interstitial"
      onPress={() => {
        interstitial.show()
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks But I just added a simple function of dismiss at the end and it worked without any error
the following is the code for it

```
let [count,setCount]=useState(0)

    function showInterstitial(){
      console.log("before count", count)
      count=count+1;
      setCount(count);
      if((count%2) == 0)
      {
          console.log("error a")
          AdMobInterstitial.removeAllListeners();
          AdMobInterstitial.setAdUnitID("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/8691691433");
          // AdMobInterstitial.setAdUnitID("ca-app-pub-9880348026808678/8849237784");
          console.log("error aa")
          AdMobInterstitial.requestAdAsync().then(() => {
            console.log("add started");
              AdMobInterstitial.showAdAsync().catch((e) => console.log(e));
          });
          // AdMobInterstitial.dismissAdAsync()
      }
      else
      {
          console.log("counter else: ", count)
      }
      AdMobInterstitial.dismissAdAsync()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AdMobInterstitial.setAdUnitID(adInterstitialUnitID);
AdMobInterstitial.requestAdAsync({ servePersonalizedAds: true })
.then(async () => {
await AdMobInterstitial.showAdAsync();
setTimeout(() => {
//Here Write your code after user seen ad
}, 3000);
setLoading(false);
})
.catch((error) => console.log(error))
.finally(() => {
setTimeout(() => {
AdMobInterstitial.dismissAdAsync();
}, 1000);
});
```